# Detach event from recurring events

Tags: calendar, recurring-events

When I edit a recurring event in sharepoint calendar I can decide whether I want to edit only one date or the whole series. If I edit just a single event all is fine as long as I don't edit the series afterwards that is containing this event because in this case also the edited events will be reset.

For background information: I have to note my working hours in advance into a sharepoint calendar. As they are normally the same every day I realize this for convenience reasons by a recurring event that is set to weekly repetition on all the weekdays that I work on. As things are changing I edit the event of a single day to fit my changed work hours.

However, every now and then it happens that my whole schedule changes and I have to change all my future work hours. The easiest thing would be now to change the series of recurring events to give it an end date where the schedule changes and start a new series at that point. Unfortunately giving an end point to a recurring event is a change in recurrence and therefore all exceptions to the recurring event (meaning all my changed work hours) get deleted.

Is there a possibility to some kind of "detach" an event from an event series so that it is no longer part of the series? Or any other best practice to solve such highly regular but sometimes irregular events with a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a real solution but a workaround that doesn't cause too much additional work but avoids the problem of setting an end date to the series and therefore being forced to edit the whole series: If I set the events to recurring but for a limited timespan (lets say one month or so) then I can apply any changes only to single events without the need to edit the whole series again.